# How to define and access a list in python

Tags: c#, python

I am new to Python. Basically I am a C#.Net guy. I trying to write the below C# code in my Python language but I could not find a correct way to define and access a list type class in Python.

Here is my C#.Net code

```
public class Person
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
public string Street { get; set; }
public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

In the above class I can access multiple addresses by creating an instance to Person.

Here is my Python code

```
class Address(object):
Street=""
Zip=""

class Person(object):
Name=""
# here i need to define a list of Address type?
```

How can I access multiple addresses by creating instance to Person class in Python?

Comment: You might want to check the [relevant section in the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Comment: Python lists aren't typed, just create a list and append address objects to it.

Comment: Please use tutorials for learning

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Python code analogous to your C# code:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.addresses = []

class Address():
    def __init__(self):
        self.street = ""
        self.zip = ""
```

You can add an Address to `self.addresses` with `append` (or anything else really, since Python is dynamically typed). I reccommend reading the official tutorials to understand why this works - it's all in there.